# Reading an array from a binary file in c returns incorrect values

Tags: c, arrays, file, binary

I just started learning files in c language and i have a problem with my code. It works just fine writing in the binary file, but when im trying to read the values back, it returns one less value and also different values for the array. 
I am aware that probably i've made a dumb mistake, if you could help me understand i would be greatful.
This is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()

{
    FILE *f;
    if ((f=fopen("fis.bin","wb"))==NULL)
    {
        printf ("Error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int *v;
    int n,x;
    char s[100];
    scanf("%d",&n);
    v=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&v[i]);

        x=fprintf(f,"%d\n",v[i]);
        if (x<0)
            perror("Error:");
    }
    fclose(f);

    int *cit;

    cit=(int*)calloc(n,sizeof(int));

    if ((f=fopen("fis.bin","rb"))==NULL)
    {
        printf ("Error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fseek(f,0,SEEK_END);

    int sz = ftell(f)/sizeof(v[0]);

    fseek(f,0,0);

    int i=0;

    if(!fread(cit,sizeof(int),sz,f))
        perror("err: ");

    for (i=0; i<sz; i++)
        printf("%d\n",cit[i]);



    printf("\n");

    free(v);
    free(cit);


    fclose(f);

}
```

Comment: I think we would be able to help if we had the file.

Comment: Well, the output is the same no matter the values in the file. I tried with only 3 values and the sz returns 2 instead of 3 . Dont know why

Comment: `int sz = ftell(f)/sizeof(v[0]);` does not suit your requirement as `ftell` returns position in bytes, consider you have written `1 2 3 4` `ftell` returns  `7` but what  you want is `16` bytes.

Comment: Read the documentation of every used function (e.g. [scanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)). Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You're writing to the file using `fprintf()` and reading th same file using `fread()`.    The chances of the two formats lining up - for an array of `int` - is zero.

Comment: Ohh, thank you so much. I didnt know that i cant combine functions like fprintf and fread. Do you have any idea why the sz was originally wrong? I dont understand how it is related to the 2 functions mentioned above..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are writing to the file using `fprintf`.

where as `fprintf` writes `string` representation of `integers`.
For example, when you  write `2` to the file you are writing `"2"` as string of size 1 byte.

```
x=fprintf(f,"%d\n",v[i]);
```

Thus replace `fprintf` with `fwrite` as below.

```
fwrite(&v[i], sizeof(v[0]), 1, f);
```

> `fwrite` writes binary representation of integer.

Comment: Thank youu. So each time im writing to a binary file i should use fwrite, but when im writing to a text file i can also use fprintf?

Comment: @MaryPoppins Nope, `fprintf and fscanf` are there to write and read formatted text, while `fwrite and fread` are there to write and read binary. Just don't mix up the things.

Comment: Okay. Well i had a txt file and i used fwrite and fread to write and read an array to and from the file and it worked. So thats why i asked.. marked it, thank you